# Can I use Kestrel web server in an existing .NET 4.5 process?

Tags: asp.net, kestrel-http-server

I'm looking for a .NET web server that can be incorporated into existing process without much fuss.   The process currently runs on .net 4.5 on Windows 10.   Can I use the kestrel http server in this context?

Can anyone point me to a "hello world" level example of using Kestrel?

### Updated...

I found a [minimal hosting example](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/hosting.html) in the ASP.NET docs, but it won't compile.  Since the docs seem in error, I'm logging it as [an issue for this](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1106) on GitHub.

Comment: It supports .NET Framework 4.5.1, https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel/project.json but before Microsoft fixes the tooling, it would be painful to use the code in a traditional .NET project (.csproj).

Comment: I removed the useiisintegration call. However, i am getting the error "Unable to load DLL 'libuv': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}

Comment: Did you get this solved? I saw elsewhere that if you target w32 or x64 rather than anyCPU it would work.  The github link is dead , so is there a code sample of this working?